# Joining tables with common columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables as follows.
Table A:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
 3    6    300
 2    3    400
 3    5    200
```

and this is Table B:

```
Col1 Col2 Col4
 3    5    500
 3    7    900
 2    4    300
 2    3    100
```

The output I want is: Table C

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
 3    5    200  500
 3    7    0    900
 2    4    0    300
 2    3    400  100
 3    6    300  0
```

Values in col3 and col4 are a function of values in col1 and col2. I wish to join Tables A and B as shown in the example below. I have tried full outer join but it does not return zeros where there are no records and it returns all columns from both the tables. How do I get the output as shown? Thank you.

Comment: Is this a joke?  Do you have HTML tables or SQL tables?

Comment: SQL tables. I am new to the community and do not know how to display tables in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full outer join is a good idea, use NVL to sobstitute null values with 0

```
select NVL(t1.col1,t2.col1), NVL(t1.col2,t2.col2), NVL(col3,0), NVL(col4,0)
from t1
full outer join t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

With another table:

```
select NVL(NVL(t1.col1,t2.col1),t3.col1), 
       NVL(NVL(t1.col2,t2.col2),t3.col2), 
       NVL(col3,0), NVL(col4,0), NVL(col5,0)
from t1
full outer join t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
full outer join t3
on t1.col1 = t3.col1 and t1.col2 = t3.col2
   and t2.col1 = t3.col1 and t2.col2 = t3.col2
```

Sorry I've not tried it ... tell me if there is some problem.

Comment: I don't know how you wrote that query using a bunch of HTML tables, but I'm upvoting this.

Comment: Probably clicked on the `run snippet` button .. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I was to join a 3rd table now with col1, col2 and col5 in a similar fashion, how will this query change?